# How to send push notification from codeigniter project

Tags: php, codeigniter, push-notification

I am working on a codeigniter project. How to send push notifications to ios and Android devices?

Comment: This may help https://github.com/changyy/codeigniter-library-notification

Comment: Use APNS Push Library  , its very easy with functions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are some libraries available.

1. Firebase (sends push notification to both IOS and android ).
2. GCM (sends only to android and it is also considered as outdated and overtaken
   by  Firebase).

Some links which might help you .

https://gist.github.com/joashp/b2f6c7e24127f2798eb2
https://github.com/mac-cain13/notificato

Comment: You can refer this Github repository for FCM https://github.com/ImWizeon/Codeigniter-FCM-Library